# Why do I see 12 decimals in my custom refinable integer column on my search page?

Tags: search, refinement-panel, refiner

I have a SharePoint 2013 portal and are customize the searchpage. I have add some refinables. All the refinables are working fine. Only one refinable is not like how I expected. I have a custom column from the type integer. I have add this column to my refinables. But I see to much zero's after the integer. Why is SharePoint doing this?

I have mapped the manages property "RefinableDecimal01" to my crawled property "ows_q_NMBR_Voorraad".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's an artifact of choosing Decimal. I ended up mapping mine to Integer and it worked fine. In my case I did not care about the values below the decimal. I you need them you could always create a custom refiner that handled the values formatting them the way you liked.

Comment: Can you please give me more information about your last sense (create a custom refiner that handled the values formatting them the way you liked)?

Comment: If converting the values to into will not work for you, you can just create a refiner (Display Template) and then perform the necessary rounding and formatting in the refiner. I discuss Display Templates in my SPC Session: http://bit.ly/abSPC322 refiners are the same.